# In a Feynman diagram, how can the length of some lines be extended for the purpose of clarity?

Tags: feynman, feynmp

I have a Feynman diagram like the following:

[image]

The red lines on the right connecting the final states overlap with the black lines of the Feynman diagram. If the lowermost and uppermost black lines of the t quarks were extended beyond the extent of the rightmost black lines of the b quarks, then the overlapping would be lessened and the diagram made possibly clearer.

How could this be done?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\unitlength=1.00 mm

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{fmffile}{gg}
\begin{fmfchar*}(100,70)

\fmfleftn{i}{2}
\fmfrightn{o}{4}

\fmf{curly}{i1,v1}
\fmf{curly}{i2,v2}
\fmf{fermion}{o1,v1}
\fmf{fermion}{v1,v3}
\fmf{fermion}{v3,v2}
\fmf{fermion}{v2,o4}

\fmf{curly, label=\(g\)}{v3,v4}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v4}
\fmf{fermion}{v4,o3}

\fmf{double,fore=red}{o1,o2}
\fmf{double,fore=red}{o1,o3}
\fmf{double,fore=red}{o1,o4}
\fmf{double,fore=red}{o2,o3}
\fmf{double,fore=red}{o2,o4}
\fmf{double,fore=red}{o3,o4}

\fmflabel{\(g\)}{i1}
\fmflabel{\(g\)}{i2}
\fmflabel{\(\bar{t}\)}{o1}
\fmflabel{\(\bar{b}\)}{o2}
\fmflabel{\(b\)}{o3}
\fmflabel{\(t\)}{o4}

\end{fmfchar*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shift the top quark anchor points to the right using `\fmfforce`. Adding

```
\fmfforce{xpart(vloc __o4)+50,ypart(vloc __o4)}{o4} % upper top quark
\fmfforce{xpart(vloc __o1)+50,ypart(vloc __o1)}{o1} % lower top antiquark
```

right after `\fmfrightn{o}{4}` results in

[image: feynman]

Note that `xpart(...)` returns the `x` coordinate of a point, and `vloc` switches from „vertex mode“ to „immediate mode“. Also note that `vloc` requires the point to be prefixed with `__`.

Comment: Just in case you wonder, the `50` are in `pt` units, but you can use others as well, e.g. `20mm`.

Comment: You can also specify the new `x`-coordinate using the built-in `w`-variable (which is the width of the original figure), e.g. `\fmfforce{1.1*w,ypart(vloc __o4)}{o4}`